# How to cast an IQueryable to a type List (Of Orders)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I asked a question a few days ago on how to add paging though records to a web page using an index based solution.

I need to be able to change the sort of  the list of orders using two parameters: strSortBy, and strSortDirection.

I am attempting to do it using IQueryable query:

```
query = temporders.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Order]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Order]'.
```

Line:

```
orderList.Items = query
```

This is my code for the up(next) button:

```
Dim temporders As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Order) = orderList.Items

If Not temporders Is Nothing And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSortBy) Then
    Dim query As IQueryable = Nothing
    query = temporders.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
    orderList.Items = query
End If
```

What am I doing wrong in the assignment? Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I change my code so I apply the OrderBy to the oderList.Items instead that to the tempOrders

```
orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection)
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to make it work this way:

```
orderList.Items = orderList.Items.AsQueryable.OrderBy(strSortBy + " " + strSortDirection).ToList
```

Comment: What is the type of `orderList.Items`?

Comment: orderList declaration: Dim orderList As Orders. I think it is of string type, by looking at the object definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `ToList` to materialize a query as a list:

```
orderList.Items = query.ToList()
```

But you seem to be casting, calling, `AsQueryable`, etc. when it's not clear *why*.

If `orderList.Items` is a `List (Of Order)` then why are you casting it?  If it's not then you may not need to do any casting at all.

Comment: I tried that but I get a message:  BC30456: 'ToList' is not a member of 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. I was casting it in an older version of my code, sorry, I updated that line as I am actually coding it.

Comment: `ToList` is an extension method on `IEnumerable` which `IQueryable` implements.  I'd normally think you weren't importing the `Linq` namespace, but since the other Linq methods seem to work I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: `ToList` requires an `IQueryable(Of Order)` to produce a `List(Of Order)`.

Comment: @JonHanna Or an `IEnumerable(Of Order)`.  It's not clear (due to the `AsQueryable` call) if the source is an `IQueryable` or an `IEnumerable`.